# How to update multiple child node values at same time using transaction in Firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, transactions

I'm developing a mobile app using React Native and Firebase with Firebase Real TIme database. Let's think, I have some data like this.

```
myRoot
  |
  |---myValue1: 0
  |---myValue2: 0
```

I want to increment the values of both `myValue1` and `myValue2` by 1 at the same time. How can I do that using `transaction` in `Firebase`?